# Estimating the cost of future projects: where do I start?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, estimation

#### Objective

I'm doing my bachelor's assignment at a manufacturer of custom staircases and balustrades (*parts*). Their quotation system (estimating the price of a proposed *project*) is quite burdensome and often inaccurate. Their calculators should be able to:

- take the design for which a customer wants a quotation
- score each of the *parts* in the design on several features (i.e. size: length/width/height, complexity, shape, and to what extent a design is a copy of a previously designed *part*, or of another *part* within the *project*)
- score the *project* on several features (i.e. distance from company, whether a Building Information Model is available, etc.)
- have the estimated cost roll out, preferably broken down per *part* or *action* (i.e. in the case of design meetings, the cost of which is based both on the size of the project and the distance to the customer)

The desired outcome of my project is similar to the model for linear regression, where the cost function consists of variables and their coefficients (or something similar to that for categorical/boolean variables, of which I have a number). This is desired both because my project needs to fit within a bigger project, and because that outcome would allow the company to adapt the model to new data without much experience in data analytics, after my departure.

#### Question

There are a number of questions I have, but the biggest cause of confusion to me is that, as it seems, the *parts* (which have features) are themselves also a feature of the *project*. From this, the problem arises that linear regression and such methods don't seem to apply, or at least: I'm not sure how. And I'm not sure what other method I can use, or how I can make the methods fit.

So: what method should I use to solve this? Where can I find more information, or what should I learn in order to solve this problem? Do you have any solutions to the problems posed?

Fyi: I've started some work in Python, and that's what I have most experience with. It's not much, but I've done a few courses in it, incl. a Basic Machine Learning master's course. Other than that I only really know Excel (and some Visual Basic for Excel, though that's been a while). No experience with R or SPSS.

Also, if this problem description is not clear, let me know!

Comment: From what I understand the number of inputs can change from project to project, am I right?

Comment: Correct! And that seems to me one of the hardest parts.

Comment: Because it is... usually machine learning algorithm work with predefined number of input. E.g. if you have to classify image each image have the same size. One possible idea it is to define a fixed set of parameter shared by all the possible project

Comment: @AlbertoZancanaro right... So, for example, you would recommend I reduce all staircases and balustrades in a project to a single JointBalustrade and JointStaircase? So I could, for example, add up the sizes of the different balustrades. And then I could try to average out the factors which determine the difficulty of engineering the different parts.

There is probaby going to be quite a lot of information loss in that, though...

Comment: Yeah that's an option. Otherwise you can try to create multiple algorithm (e.g. one that estimate the cost of the staircases, one for balustrades etc). The problem with this approach is that can be very time consuming